# Transparent Color NullpointerException

Tags: java, android

So i have a nightmode filter app, which has transparent activity on the mainactivity, and in the middle of the screen theres a button which should change the transparent activity to black "Screen filter" for night mode. The problem I am having is 
Much appriciated if someone answers
    W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
    W/System.err:     at com.example.kenert.allinoneapp.Nightmode.turnNightOn(Nightmode.java:91)
    W/System.err:     at com.example.kenert.allinoneapp.Nightmode.nightmodeButtonClicked(Nightmode.java:78)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Mainactivity code :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class Nightmode extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean nightmodeOnOff;
    public ImageButton modeOnOffButton;
    private int brightness;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActivity(new Intent(this,NightmodeFilter.class));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nightmode);

        modeOnOffButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nightmodeOnOffButton);
        nightmodeOnOff = false;


        int prog;
        //Seekbar
        SeekBar skbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.nightModeBar);
        skbar.setMax(255);
        skbar.setKeyProgressIncrement(127);

        try {
            brightness = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        skbar.setProgress(brightness);

        skbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
                if (progress <= 25) {
                    brightness = 25;
                } else {
                    brightness = progress;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams lpp = getWindow().getAttributes();
                lpp.screenBrightness = brightness/(float)255;
                getWindow().setAttributes(lpp);
            }
        });

    }


    public void nightmodeButtonClicked(View view) {
        try {
            if (nightmodeOnOff) {
                nightmodeOnOff = false;

                turnNightOff();
            } else {
                nightmodeOnOff = true;
                turnNightOn();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void turnNightOn() {

        try {
            modeOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.nightmodeonbutton);

            findViewById(R.id.activity_nightmode_filter).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99000000"));



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void turnNightOff() {

        try {
            modeOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.nightmodeonoffbutton);
            findViewById(R.id.activity_nightmode).setBackgroundColor(0x66000000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        turnNightOff();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        turnNightOff();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        turnNightOff();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        turnNightOff();
    }
}
```

Transparent Activity code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class NightmodeFilter extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nightmode_filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Transparent activity xml and theme :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_nightmode_filter"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Transparent"





    tools:context="com.example.kenert.allinoneapp.NightmodeFilter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


</LinearLayout>
```

Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: findViewById(R.id.activity_nightmode_filter).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99000000")) This is the line that is getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you main activity have the visibility on "activity_nightmode_filter", can't you put this function in your NightmodeFilter activity ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the view you are trying to get a reference to is the activity view itself, so when you call `findViewById`, it will return a null reference.

One way to change the activity background color is like this: in your `onCreate` method, after you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_nightmode);`, get the decorView and set its background color:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundCo‌​lor(Color.parseColor‌​("#99000000"))
```